# I can't setup proxy in mern stack(react-vite) and do not know the reason

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, vite

I'm developing mern stack web application with react from vite.js and have a problem to deal with proxy.

my client side runs at `http://localhost:3000` and server side runs at `http://localhost:5000`.

usually I use http-proxy-midlleware to connect my server and client like below

src/setupProxy.jsx

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app){
  app.use(
      createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
          target: 'http://localhost:5000',
          changeOrigin: true
      })
  )
};
```

However, It didn't work and still sent to localhost:3000 when I post data to server with axios. I googled it and figured out that with vite.js I need to use vite.config.js

so I set up vite.config.js like below

import { defineConfig, HttpProxy } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        host: true,
        port : 3000,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
        
    },
  

})
```

and tried axios call again.

```
const result = await axios.post('api/users/login', dataToSubmit)
                .then(res => res.data);
            return result;
```

However, contrary to my expectation, It still sent to 3000 and I do not have a clue about what is going wrong :/

```
xhr.js:210          POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 404 (Not Found)
```

could you tell me how to fix it? thanks for reading, your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

It's required to specify `secure: false` like this. [Reference](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/564)

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        host: true,
        port : 3000,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false
            }
        }
        
    },
  

})
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too.

My backend runs on `http://localhost:8080`, while my frontend runs on `http://localhost:3000`.

To resolve the cross-origin issue, I used the proxy alternative, but every request was returning a 404 error.

My solution was to add the `rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, "")` function in the vite settings file.

Finally, the final result of the file was:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your port in vite.config.js file is set to 3000. So you have to set your target in src/setupProxy.jsx to 'http://localhost:3000'.

hope it helps